# StreamContent from HttpResponseMessage into XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, stream

I'm calling an existing get method from a WebApi Controller which has this code (I cannot modify it)

```
   [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:\\document.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        string str = xmldoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
        return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(str, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml") };

    }
```

I've been trying to read this information like this

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/info");
            HttpContent content = rm.Content;
```

I get a StreamContent but what I like to do now is to read this content and try to deserialize it into a Xml Document in order to read the nodes.

How can I get this information from the Stream Content of the HttpContent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string response;

using(var http = new HttpClient())
{
    response = await http.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/api/info");
}

var xml = new XmlDataDocument();
xml.LoadXml(response);
```

You can use GetStringAsync to get a string instead of an HttpContent object. You also missed the **await** in your GetAsync.

Note: code has not been tested

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I get the response with all the xml structure (w/o the ?xml and namespace. this is ok) BUT when I arrive to LoadXML, it throws an exception of Illegal characters in path. My string response is a collection of employees "<Employees><Employee ID="1"><Name>Smith</Name><DateOfBirth>1990-09-15</DateOfBirth></Employee><Employee ID="2"><Name>Scott</Name><DateOfBirth /></Employee></Employees>"

Comment: What's the actual string that you get back look like?

Comment: I tried that. It didn't have any errors that's why I'm asking. Can you confirm that it is exactly what you're getting when debugging?

Comment: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was using .Load instead of .LoadXml method. Thank you so much.