# Send and Receive XmlDocument on .Net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, xmldocument

I have to send a XmlDocument to an API on Framework 4.5.1.
In the sending API, I tried to send, via POST, the xmlStream using MultipartFormDataContent:

```cs
 var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
 {
  { new StreamContent(options.XmlStream), "xmlFile", "filename" }
 };
```

**In the receiving end, I can't use IFormFile, because of the API version.**

**I also have to avoid base64.**

I tried to receive it as MultipartFormDataContent, but it is not working.

So, I need this to work in any way, but I can't update the Framework in the API's, since it could just crash everything.

**Sending API: .Net Standard 2.0**

**Receiving API: .Net 4.5.1**

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET 5 is no longer supported nor is .NET Framework v4.5.1.  See [.NET Lifecylcle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) and [.NET Framework Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) for more information

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

Comment: Something like this perhaps? [StreamContent from HttpResponseMessage into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31822141/2596334)